# Select who change with other select in angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So, I would like to do a select list which changes when an other selects list values changes (ex: when county change , stats select list change) in AngularJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use hierarchical data like this;

```
[
    {
        name: "item1",
        subitems : ["subitem11","subitem12","subitem13"]
    },
    {
        name: "item2",
        subitems : ["subitem21","subitem22"]
    },
    {
        name: "item3",
        subitems : ["subitem31","subitem32","subitem33"]
    }
];
```

You can use this markup;

```
<select ng-model="selecteditem" ng-options="item as item.name for item in list"></select>
<select ng-model="selectedsubitem" ng-options="subitem for subitem in selecteditem.subitems"></select>
```

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6A8aF/)

Answer (score 0):

Your data binding should already be taking care of this... here's a simple example.

```
<select ng-model="country" ng-options="country.name for country in countries">
<select ng-model="region?" ng-options="region.name for region in country.regions">
```

When `country` changes, so will `country.regions`, so the other select will update as well.

Comment: sorry iam beginner with angularJS , so where i will do the datas of countries and regions ?